# Posting Message to Fan Page Comment using XID

Tags: facebook, post, web, comments

I am currently trying to post a message to a fan page using XID. I was wondering how I would be able to post a message using XID.

I am currently able to retrieve the comment using xid using the following method:
https://graph.facebook.com/316366498417595?access_token=_TOKEN_KEY_

Would anyone can be kind enough to tell me how I can post a message using the XID. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can post a message by doing a similar call:

`https://graph.facebook.com/316366498417595/feed?message=_MESSAGE_&access_token=_TOKEN_KEY_`

Comment: I tried that code but it still doesn't work, have you tried it before?

Comment: It works. Try using the Graph API Explorer to test it. developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/